# WIN 2012 DNS Issue

Tags: windows, domain-name-system, active-directory

I am troubleshooting an issue with the dns server on the main DC in our forest. I ended up at this point while trying to get a second controller up and running.

Current results for dcdiag /test:dns are below

```
Directory Server Diagnosis

Performing initial setup:
Trying to find home server...
Home Server = ad
* Identified AD Forest.
Done gathering initial info.

Doing initial required tests

   Testing server: ad\AD
      Starting test: Connectivity
         ......................... AD passed test Connectivity

Doing primary tests

Testing server: ad\AD

  Starting test: DNS

     DNS Tests are running and not hung. Please wait a few minutes...
     ......................... AD passed test DNS

Running partition tests on : ForestDnsZones

Running partition tests on : DomainDnsZones

Running partition tests on : Schema

Running partition tests on : Configuration

Running partition tests on : domain

Running enterprise tests on : domain.com
   Starting test: DNS
     Test results for domain controllers:

        DC: ad.domain.com
        Domain: domain.com


           TEST: Basic (Basc)
              Warning: adapter
              [00000011] Intel(R) 82574L Gigabit Network Connection has
              invalid DNS server: 127.0.0.1 (AD)
              Error: all DNS servers are invalid

        TEST: Records registration (RReg)
           Error: Record registrations cannot be found for all the network
           adapters

     Summary of test results for DNS servers used by the above domain
     controllers:

        DNS server: 192.168.0.26 (AD)
           1 test failure on this DNS server
           Name resolution is not functional.   _ldap._tcp.domain.com. failed on the DNS server 192.168.0.26

     Summary of DNS test results:

                                        Auth Basc Forw Del  Dyn  RReg Ext
        _________________________________________________________________
        Domain: domain.com
           ad                           PASS FAIL PASS PASS PASS FAIL n/a

     ......................... domain.com failed test DNS
```

So I've been trying to troubleshoot what the Basc error might be, but at this point I'm not sure, and any searching about it has been fruitless.

I am glad to provide any more info or diagnostic output.

Edit: ipconfig /all

```
Windows IP Configuration

Host Name . . . . . . . . . . . . : ad
Primary Dns Suffix  . . . . . . . : domain.com
Node Type . . . . . . . . . . . . : Hybrid
IP Routing Enabled. . . . . . . . : No
WINS Proxy Enabled. . . . . . . . : No
DNS Suffix Search List. . . . . . : domain.com

Ethernet adapter Ethernet0:

Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : 
Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Intel(R) 82574L Gigabit Network  Connection
Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-0C-29-3F-20-F4
DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::b916:e720:ea8b:a326%14(Preferred) 
IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.0.26(Preferred) 
Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : fe80::1:1%14
                                   192.168.0.3
DHCPv6 IAID . . . . . . . . . . . : 352324649
DHCPv6 Client DUID. . . . . . . . : 00-01-00-01-1B-C4-A2-0C-00-0C-29-A9-80-01
DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : 127.0.0.1
NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Enabled

Tunnel adapter isatap.{715545D0-9D5A-4707-91A2-876364FA3227}:

Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : 
Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Microsoft ISATAP Adapter
Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-E0
DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes

Tunnel adapter Teredo Tunneling Pseudo-Interface:

Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : 
Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Teredo Tunneling Pseudo-Interface
Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-E0
DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
```

Thanks,
Cam

Comment: Start with the basics, post the output of `ipconfig/all` from the DC in question. It looks like the DC might be using 127.0.0.1 as the first DNS server in it's TCP/IP client settings (on the NIC), which is not correct. Then run the AD and DNS BPA's on the server and post those results here.

Comment: Both the AD and DNS BPA results are empty.

Comment: Nope that was a lie, I figured it out, I will edit the main post in a minute.

Comment: What is the issue with the DNS server?  Is it not responding to queries?

Comment: It responds to queries, and other client computers can connect to it, but I can't get a second domain to join it.

Comment: You've got 127.0.0.1 listed as the only DNS server in the TCP/IP settings of the server. While the DCPROMO process does make that setting, the BPA will generate a warning if 127.0.0.1 is configured as the first DNS server. Set the servers actual ip address as primary DNS and set 127.0.0.1 as secondary DNS, then reboot the server and check it again.

Comment: @joeqwerty that fixed the dcdiag errors, and let me connect!

Thanks so much for all your help.

Comment: Glad to help...

Comment: @joeqwerty I know it's not exactly an essay, but please, post answers as answers so we can vote on them...

Comment: On what addresses is your DNS set up to listen to? All addresses or specific ones?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got 127.0.0.1 listed as the only DNS server in the TCP/IP settings of the server. The DCPROMO process does make that setting, but the BPA will generate a warning if 127.0.0.1 is configured as the first DNS server. Set the servers actual ip address as primary DNS and set 127.0.0.1 as secondary DNS, then reboot the server and check it again

Answer (score 1):

I see this is answered already, but I wanted to follow up. This is a best practices issue. Run the BPA for DNS, and you'll see that it's no longer recommended to have the loopback address as the first DNS server. The IP of the server, in a single DNS server environment, should the the primary, then if you want you can have the loopback address in the secondary slot.

This is actually the kind of thing the BPA was designed to take care of though. After you're done deploying AD, you ought to run the DNS and AD BPAs. Many issues that are strange and difficult to troubleshoot/track down could be avoided by running the BPA early and often (after configuration changes, new servers being added, etc).